# Slicing a DataFrame in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape, multi-index

I have a problem with a df in pandas. Lets suppose I have this dataframe:

```
k = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

k = pd.DataFrame(k).T
```

Which is a 1x12 dataframe and I want to get a df with 4 columns of it, like k4:

```
k1 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4])
k2 = pd.DataFrame( [5,6,7,8])
k3 =  pd.DataFrame([9,10,11,12])
frames = [k1,k2,k3]
k4 = pd.concat(frames, axis = 1).T
```

My original df is much larger than k but its number of columns is multiple of 4
and I want to slice it into a 4 columns df. I guess it could be something
related to i%4 == 0 but I dont really know how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

I miss a problem. I should have trasposed k4. Sorry guys.

TO sum up, i have a large row with a len multiple of 4, much larger than 12:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
```

And I need to make a df with 4 columns, with a change of row on each 4 elements:

```
  0   1   2   3
0  1   2   3   4
0  5   6   7   8
0  9  10  11  12
```

Comment: `frames = [pd.DataFrame([i:i+4]) for i in range(len(k)/4)]` Not sure what you exactly want though.

Comment: edited, mate.   Now I think it is more visual . Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create `MultiIndex` in columns first by floor divide and modulo and then use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), for remove first level of `MultiIndex` of `index` add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
k = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

k = pd.DataFrame(k).T
k.columns = [k.columns // 4, k.columns % 4]
print (k)
   0           1           2            
   0  1  2  3  0  1  2  3  0   1   2   3
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12

print (k.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
   0  1   2
0  1  5   9
1  2  6  10
2  3  7  11
3  4  8  12
```

EDIT:

Only need `0` for swap first level of `MultiIndex`, not default last level

```
print (k.stack(0).reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
   0   1   2   3
0  1   2   3   4
1  5   6   7   8
2  9  10  11  12
```

Or swap modulo with floor dividing:

```
k = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

k = pd.DataFrame(k).T
k.columns = [k.columns % 4, k.columns // 4]
print (k)
   0  1  2  3  0  1  2  3  0   1   2   3
   0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  2   2   2   2
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12

print (k.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
   0   1   2   3
0  1   2   3   4
1  5   6   7   8
2  9  10  11  12
```

Another numpy solution with [`numpy.ndarray.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html#numpy.ndarray.reshape) is faster:

```
k = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

print (pd.DataFrame(np.array(k).reshape(-1,4)))
   0   1   2   3
0  1   2   3   4
1  5   6   7   8
2  9  10  11  12
```

Comment: I am on it, I just don't understand what does the -1 means, as I understand 4 is the cols size of the matrix.  @jezrael

Comment: You can find it [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape) - last sample `# the unspecified value is inferred`

Comment: Thanks mate. I understand now how it works. You place the -1 either on the cols either on the rows in order to adapt your new size of array to the other number. Thanks again.

Comment: Exactly. Glad can help you! Good luck!